# How to know the status of media player in session via Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

How do i know whether my media player is running via a service is either running or stopped. currently i am invoking the service using actions.

How can i check the Media player status in my MainActivity ? so that i can make appropriate changes to the UI!

Below is my code of service that implements mediaplayer.

```
    public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.demo.tron.mediaplayerasaservice.PLAY";
    private static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.demo.tron.mediaplayerasaservice.STOP";

    public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // initialize it here
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            try{
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de:80/antenne");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STOP)){
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

This is the code that invokes the media player service via MAIN ACTIVITY :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                intent.setAction("com.demo.tron.mediaplayerasaservice.PLAY");
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the service is already running or not and then take appropriate action :

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call the method isServiceRunning anywhere like this:

```
isServiceRunning(YourServiceClass.class)
```

Define a PlayerConstants class to keep track of player state. It will contain all static variables :

```
public class PlayerConstants {
    //List of Songs
    public static ArrayList<MediaItem> SONGS_LIST = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
    //song number which is playing right now from SONGS_LIST
    public static int SONG_NUMBER = 0;
    //song is playing or paused
    public static boolean SONG_PAUSED = true;
}
```

Now you need to check if the service is running, if running, song can be paused or already playing, you can get pause state from PlayerConstants, else the song is playing. If service is not running, no song is playing. Accordingly you can handle your UI.

Comment: Your way of finding whether service is active is not so good. Also what after setting the constants, how do i make the MainActivity know if player is running ? Do i need to put some kind of handler that updates every second

Comment: You'll probably need a handler to post messages to activity about change in player states, ie., next/previous song, play/pause song, and a handler that posts message to activity every second about song progress update. Once activity is created, you check if service is running, if not running, no song is playing, if the service is running, check if song is in pause state or not from player constants, accordingly you can handle the UI.